# Which matrix decompositions feature permutation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory

It's well known that LU decomposition is only numerically stable if it's combined with row and/or column pivoting. It makes me wonder if there are other matrix decompositions that can profitably be combined with pivoting, that are not simply special cases of LDU decomposition with block diagonal D.

More broadly, which matrix decompositions feature permutation matrices?

The motivation for this question is to gain a unified understanding of the features of matrix decompositions.

Comment: Question author here: It looks like the RRQR decomposition is an example

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_decomposition

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler That's a good one, thanks

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, isn't the LU decomposition just a translate of the Bruhat decomposition for $\operatorname{GL}_n$?

Comment: @LSpice I would say that LU decomposition is the largest piece of Bruhat decomposition. That it to say, Bruhat decomposition is $GL_n = \bigsqcup_{w \in S_n} L w U$. The $LU$ decomposition is the observation that the $w = \mathrm{Id}$ piece covers all but a piece of measure $0$.

Comment: In various contexts, people will say that Bruhat decomposition is $\bigsqcup LwL$, $\bigsqcup LwU$, $\bigsqcup UwL$ or $\bigsqcup UwU$. This issue doesn't affect the point I am making.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, I thought that the term "LU decomposition" was often used even when there was a permutation involved, as in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#LU_factorization_with_partial_pivoting), thus allowing it to recover the whole Bruhat decomposition.  I agree that, if one restricts to the literal name, then one only recovers (a translate of) the big cell.

Comment: You may be right.

Comment: I would say that LU and LUP decompositions are somewhat distinct from Bruhat decomposition for they work for singular matrices as well.